# Find and replace text within a file using commands

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, operating-system

I want to replace a string with another string inside the file `homedir` to `home/public_html` using UNIX commands. How should I do so?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked many times before.  The best tool for your job is likely `sed`.  See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/).